# How to allow automatic resizing of UIButton to satisfy spacing constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm working on a calculator app that looks like this so far: 
[image]

The clear button is constrained to 8 pixels below the text field that's above it (which also has constraints that keep it 8 pixels from the edges in the top left corner), the 7 button is constrained to 8 pixels below the clear button, etc. and all of these buttons have a constraint that says they are all equal heights.

My goal is to add a constraint that says the 0 button is 8 pixels above the bottom of the parent view, and then have all the buttons automatically resize to maintain the size and spacing constraints between them. However, adding this constraint just generates some conflicts rather than resizing the buttons. Is there a simple way to tell my app to resize the buttons to satisfy constraints? This is a picture of what I'm hoping these buttons would look like if all goes as planned:

[image]

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is as a reason for varying in screen height satisfying your constraints can only be done by letting one part (Above 4 blocks / 0 button) to resize itself according to the constraints set for the other part , So Insert the first 4 blocks (4*4) in a UIStackView (inside it 4 horizontal stackViews ) and make it Fill Equally

then when you give any height to 0 Button the above stackView will resize accordingly

**Note** : I know there is a button on the bottom - right that spans 2 rows , no problem add it above the design i mentioned

Comment: This method worked perfectly, but I would really appreciate a clarification on how to get the button in the bottom right to be larger. Did you mean to move it out of the stackview? The reason that this would give me issues is that my stackview is constrained to parent view edges, so I'm not really sure how I would reset the constraints of the outer & inner stackviews to accommodate the large key. Just have two of the individual inner stacks constraint to the top of the large key? Regardless, thank you so much- your comment was extremely helpful!